# как обновить локальную ветку до мастера

Tags: git, git-merge

Есть мастер и локальная ветка branch-1.
Мастер уже уехал далеко вперед, имеются конфликты между ним и branch-1.
Сделал git pull, обновил мастер свежими изменениями.
Теперь перехожу в branch-1, делаю git merge master, разрешаю конфликты и делаю результирующий коммит.
Но после этого в ветке помимо коммита слияния показаны все коммиты, что были сделаны в мастер после ответвления branch-1.
Выглядит не очень

Comment: А Вы какого поведения ожидали? `The "merge" command is used to integrate changes from another branch.`